Error: NG05105: Unexpected synthetic property @if(uploadProgress) found
I am using @if template syntax of Angular 17 in my code
    <div @if(uploadProgress)>
      <progress [value]="uploadProgress" max="100"></progress>
    </div>

When I run ng test it gives an error : "Error: NG05105: Unexpected synthetic property @if(uploadProgress) found. Please make sure that:

Either BrowserAnimationsModule or NoopAnimationsModule are imported in your application.
There is corresponding configuration for the animation named @if(uploadProgress) defined in the animations field of the @Component decorator (see https://angular.io/api/core/Component#animations)."

The error means that Angular is interpreting @if incorrectly as an animation trigger.
I dont want to import BrowserAnimationModule as this is unnecessary in my case.
How to resolve this error ?
I can use structural directive like *ngIf instead of @if but should we be forced to use *ngIf

Use it like a normal javascript if condition in HTML.
@if(uploadProgress) {
      <progress [value]="uploadProgress" max="100"></progress>
}

The reason you are getting the browser animation import missing is because angualar animations follow a similar syntax <div [@triggerName]="expression">…</div>;, so angular thinks you are tring to implement animations.

Do go through the official docs for a detailed read on this.
Built-in control flow - Angular.dev
